# Can I get a long rest in Leomund's Tiny Hut if I'm underwater and water breathing?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, rests, underwater

I'm a druid/wizard and our party is trying to do some underwater spelunking. I cast the Water Breathing ritual, so we can all breathe underwater for 24 hours. After a few hours of adventuring we've been beat up pretty badly, so I proposed that we rest in Leomund's Tiny Hut. Since it lasts for 8 hours, we would be able to be protected for the duration of a long rest. The question remains, though: what happens underwater with Tiny Hut? The only real guidance comes from this line:

> The atmosphere inside the space is comfortable and dry, regardless of the **weather** outside.

Would the hut empty itself of water? If it stayed water-logged, would we still be able to complete a long rest, since we could breathe?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Being underwater does not prevent long-resting

There are no explicit rules which prevent or impede resting whilst underwater, so you would still be able to rest if the hut was waterlogged.

For what its' worth, the hut will not be waterlogged. It will be

> comfortable and dry

as stated in the spell description. The additional clause 'regardless of the weather outside' describes the effect in more detail, but does not restrict the the effect to weather-protection. The hut's interior is comfortable and dry, even whilst underwater.

Comment: The pedant in me initially wanted to say "dry" doesn't necessarily imply breathable air. But I suppose "comfortable" has to, at least in the sense that suffocating (however dryly) would definitely _not_ be comfortable. So now I'm imagining a House Ghallanda-made submersible involving _tiny hut_ cast on the deck of a heavily-weighted watercraft... O Eberron magic-tech shenanigans, how I adore thee!

Answer (score 5):

## The rules don't say that the hut can create air

The rules don't say that the *space* is comfortable and dry. The rules say that the *atmosphere* in the space is comfortable and dry, but if there is no atmosphere in the space, that line doesn't seem like it would create one.

A DM is welcome to rule that this spell can create breathable air, but that would be a house rule and we should not claim that it is Rules As Written.

## You can still sleep there

Nothing in the rules prevents taking a long rest while breathing water. If you wish to roleplay your character being uncomfortable doing this (due to fear the spell might suddenly fail and cause them to drown), you can do so. But if you think your character would be comfortable resting, you can just have them do that.